# Protect some methods of WCF service

Tags: wcf, certificate

I have a WCF service that runs on my machine and provides data to everyone.
I need to limit access to some methods only to a certain assembly, not depending on the user that is making the request.
I read about PrincipalPermission and certificates but I'm not sure if this can be useful to me, does anyone know how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use client certificate authentication (whether message or transport - does not matter). Add the client certificate to a trusted people store on the server side, and embed the client certificate keys (e.g PFX) in a resource.

Since not all the methods should be protected, you can create two services that expose different functionality of the same class.